# Getting middle three characters of an odd length string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, c#-4.0

I want to retrieve the middle three characters of a given odd length string.
Eg. if

```
string original = "India" //  expected output - "ndi" 
string original = "America" // expected output - "eri"
```

I tried the following code and it works as per requirement but I was wondering is there any better way for doing the same?

```
public string GetMiddleString (string original)
{
    string trimmed = string.Empty;
    int midCharIndex = (original.Length / 2);
    if ((original.Length) % 2 != 0)
    {
        trimmed = original.Substring (midCharIndex - 1, 3);
    }
    else
    {
        trimmed = original;
    }
    return trimmed;
}
```

Comment: Passing `null`, and a single character string throw exceptions, a two character string returns an incorrect result, and a 4 character string is the wrong result.

Comment: @asawyer Yes I'll edit the code accordingly in my project with exception handling and for checking null values. Thanks.

Comment: What's an "odd string"? One with a length that is an odd number? What makes you think your code will only be called with such strings?

Comment: @DourHighArch Odd in length. Sorry I should have clarified it. I'll edit in my post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

instead of the if you could use a ternary operator

```
return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(original) 
        && original.Length % 2 != 0 
        && original.Length >= 3) 
    ? original.Substring((original.Length / 2) - 1, 3) 
    : original;
```

which would be the only code inside the method needed. Added the `&& original.Length >= 3` to prevent an error.

Comment: Could use a null check.

Comment: Readability is terrible. This is a great example of how the ternary operator can be abused to make code really hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: yeah i dont disagree. The answer started as just the middle expression as the only condition, and grew for requirements.

Comment: Judicious use of whitespace makes the ternary operator much more readable, while still compact.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I came up with. Not that it really changes much to your code

```
public string GetMiddleString(string original)
{
    if (original.Length % 2 != 0 && original.Length >= 3)
        return original.Substring(original.Length / 2 - 1, 3);
    return original;
}
```

I'd make sure to check the length of the string so you don't get any exceptions.

Comment: This could also use a null check.

Answer (score 5):

Could always go LINQ!

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) && s.Length > 4 && (s.Length % 2) != 0) {
    return new string(s.Skip((s.Length / 2) - 1).Take(3).ToArray());
}
else { return string.Empty; }
```

Comment: Does this code check it the length of the string is odd or not?

Comment: @rahuldwivedi Added the check for odd lengthed string.

Comment: Why would length need to be greater than four? Can't you take the middle three characters from a string of length three? Also, this eliminates strings that are all whitespace, which is not one of the OP's requirements. Did you perhaps mean to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "India";
    
int midIndex = str.length()/2;
    
System.out.println(midIndex);
if(str.length() %2 !=0 && str.length() >= 3) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(midIndex-1, midIndex-1+3));
}else {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Result : ndi